# States and Router paths

Tags: reactjs

I edited my questions as I realized it was not clear:

Visit https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-glitter-7lk9i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I was using states for the purpose of having the following structure:

Header

BODY (CONTENT)

Footer

Onclick actions or other events, I used states to hide components and show components in the body content.

I then wanted to be able to access a certain page by url ex (localhost:3000/privacy) So I'm looking to use Router to do so.

When I do a switch command, it does not hide my main component and show the switch, rather it shows both of them. How do I get the UI to react to the way I was initially coding?

Comment: The proper way is to allow a route to render the component. You are updating state from the render method, which is why you are seeing the error. What is the purpose of `this.handler` and `stateSetting`? What are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example?

Comment: I Have added sandbox code to try to show what I would like to do. I would like to click the button, and have that component removed or hidden and show the new component. When I do router switches, the Landingpage component is not removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap `LandingPage` component inside `Route`. Please check below for detail.

App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Landingpage />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/businessregister">
            <BusinessRegister />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Baymax has the correct answer but answering to explain a bit more.

The `Switch` component renders routes exclusively; it matches and returns ***the first*** matched route component. The `Landingpage` component iss always being rendered by the router no matter what the path is.

By moving `Landingpage` onto a route you can conditionally render it based upon the current path. Placing it last ***and*** not specifying a path means that if any route declared before it is matched and returned then it won't render, but if no routes match, then the `Landingpage` component route will match all paths and render.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/businessregister">
            <BusinessRegister />
          </Route>
          <Route component={Landingpage} /> // <-- render if nothing matches above
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```